# Firing bomb at position of spaceship

Tags: javascript, easeljs

For a school project I have to make a moving spaceship that can drop bombs. The moving part works (it drops a bomb), but it only drops in one position. How can I edit my code so that it drops at the position of the spaceship? I've changed most of the code to English.

```
var canvas;
var stage;
var image;
var theSpaceship;
var moveRight = false;
var moveLeft = false;
var moveDown = false;
var moveUp = false;
var bombPng;
var bomb;
var loadedBomb = false;

function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
    maakPlaatje();
    document.onkeydown = handleKeyDown;
    document.onkeyup = handleKeyUp;
    new createjs.Ticker.setFPS(60); // frames per sec.
    createjs.Ticker.addListener(window);
}

function maakPlaatje() {
    image = new Image();
    var url = "ruimteschip.png";
    image.src = url;
    image.onload = loadGraphics;
}

function loadGraphics() {
    theSpaceship = new createjs.Bitmap(image);
    tekenPlaatje();
}

function tekenPlaatje() {
    theSpaceship.x = 0;
    theSpaceship.y = 0;
    stage.addChild(theSpaceship);
    stage.update();

}

function loadGraphicsKogelImage() {
    bomb = new createjs.Bitmap(bombPng);
    bomb.scaleX = bomb.scaleY = 0.1;
    bomb.x = 350;
    bomb.y = 1;
    stage.addChild(bomb);
    stage.update();
    loadedBomb = true;
    console.log(rsposx);
}

function schiet() {
    if (bomb == null) {
        bombPng = new Image();
        var url = "missile.png";
        bombPng.src = url;
        bombPng.name = 'popBitmap';
        bombPng.onload = loadGraphicsKogelImage;
    }
}

function beweegKogel() {
    //eerst checken of de bomb wel bestaat
    if (bomb != null) {
        bomb.y = bomb.y + 5;
        if (bomb.y > canvas.height) {
            stage.removeChild(bomb);
            bomb = null;
        } // end if >canvas.height
    } // end if bomb bestaat
} // end functie

function handleKeyDown(e) {
    // cross browser 'e' definieren:        
    if (!e) {
        var e = window.event;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 39) {
        // pijltje rechts ingedrukt.
        moveRight = true;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {
        // pijltje rechts ingedrukt.
        moveLeft = true;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 38) {
        // pijltje rechts ingedrukt.
        moveUp = true;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        // pijltje rechts ingedrukt.
        moveDown = true;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {
        // spatiebalk ingedrukt.
        schiet();
    } else {
        console.log("welke toets? maar het nummer is " + e.keyCode);
    }
}

function handleKeyUp(e) {
    // cross browser 'e' definieren:        
    if (!e) {
        var e = window.event;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 39) {
        moveRight = false;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {
        moveLeft = false;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        moveDown = false;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 38) {
        moveUp = false;
    }
}

var speed = 10;

function tick() {
    stage.update();
    if (theSpaceship != null) {
        // indien moveRight true is, loopt het plaatje:
        if (moveRight)
            theSpaceship.x = theSpaceship.x + speed;
        if (moveLeft)
            theSpaceship.x = theSpaceship.x - speed;
        if (moveDown)
            theSpaceship.y = theSpaceship.y + speed;
        if (moveUp)
            theSpaceship.y = theSpaceship.y - speed;
        if (theSpaceship.x > canvas.width)
            theSpaceship.x = 0;
        if (theSpaceship.y > canvas.height)
            theSpaceship.y = 0;
        if (loadedBomb)
            beweegKogel();
    }


}
```

Comment: Bomb's starting position should be the location of the spaceship, you appear to have hardcoded it to 350,1. PS you might want to start it below your spaceship to avoid blowing yourself up..

Comment: Thanks for your response. I know i did that, just to see if it worked. When I put bomb.x = spaceship.x, nothing happens, and I don't really know how to make it work.

Comment: Holy..... It should have been theSpaceship.x. How could I not have seen that?! I'm sorry guys.. It's been solved.